# Airflow webserver suddenly stopped starting

Tags: python, gunicorn, airflow, airflow-scheduler

My airflow webserver suddenly stopped starting. When I try to start webserver it does not come up with UI.

I tried reseting db as `airflow resetdb` and `airflow initdb` restarting all the services. Downgrading Gunicorn and upgrading it again. Restarting my linux machine, however, nothing has changed.

Logs of webserver is following:

```
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14978] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14978] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (14978)
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14978] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14983] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14983
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14984] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14984
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14985] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14985
[2019-05-17 08:08:00 +0000] [14986] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14986
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,179] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,279] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,324] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,342] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,376] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,435] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,521] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-05-17 08:08:02,524] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-05-17 08:10:00 +0000] [14978] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14984)
[2019-05-17 08:10:00 +0000] [14978] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14985)
[2019-05-17 08:10:00 +0000] [14978] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14986)
[2019-05-17 08:10:00 +0000] [14978] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14983)
[2019-05-17 08:10:01 +0000] [15161] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15161
[2019-05-17 08:10:01 +0000] [15164] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15164
[2019-05-17 08:10:01 +0000] [15167] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15167
[2019-05-17 08:10:01 +0000] [15168] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15168
[2019-05-17 08:10:03,953] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:10:04,007] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:10:04,020] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-17 08:10:04,036] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
```

Is there anyone who encountered same problem? or Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi I am experiencing a very simialr issue here. I have tried changing parameters such as webserver worker count and types without success. Suspected was due to a Kubernetes upgrade issue. Tried rolling back and no luck.

Comment: upvote may increase interest to this question

Comment: can it be the root of the problem? 

`[2019-05-17 08:10:00 +0000] [14978] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14985)
`

Comment: Maybe. I found out through the internet search that increasing gunicorn timeout time may fix the error, but it did not. Its seems like gunicorn related issue

Comment: What is your airflow set up like? It seems that for me a component called gcs-fuse caused the timeout error. We tried using gcsfuse to sync DAGs from a bucket but it's really slow. This might be the cause of timing out (Although I'm not entirely sure how it is related to Gunicorn in the web UI). Currently we use git-sync instead and the problem is not longer there.

Comment: As far as I found gscfuse is for google cloud storage. I do not use any kind of sync options. I did not find any solution until now,

Comment: @NihadAzimli Which Airflow version are you using? We started seeing this problem after upgrading to 1.10.3 and moved to smaller machines.
btw, we use Airflow in a kubernetes cluster, and re-deploying the whole cluster solves the issue temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue today, airflow webserver stopped starting. I tried a lot but was not able to determine the cause of the issue nothing worked neither resetdb nor upgradedb also reinstalling didn't work. Then I simply commented the whole code inside of my dags and manually created a .pyc file of the dags in dag folder. airflow started working again. I observed that the issue was with the dags. when I removed the dags server started functioning normally. so my advice to anyone who is facing this issue is please check your dags there is definitely something wrong within them. don't blame airflow, sometimes our own code messes with the system.

Comment: Exactly, my problem was I created ssh connection on my dag codes outside of any method. That is why whenever dag folder scanned for dags, it started ssh connection to remote machine. When I removed this piece of codes from my dags, and reset db Airflow started working without any problem

Comment: @NihadAzimli you are right, In my case, I am not using any ssh connection, but I have tried to make a piece of generic advice to anyone who has this issue because of any reason, he must first check his dags. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution that worked for me.

Make sure the `dags_folder` doesn't contain any files that are not relevant to your dags definitions and configurations.

The Airflow webserver scans periodically the `dag_folder`, and I found that if this folder is very large the scans causes the server to stall.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I figured out my problem and solved it. My problem was I created ssh connection on my dag codes outside of any method. That is why whenever dag folder scaned for dags, it started ssh connection to remote machine. When I removed this piece of codes from my dags, and reseted db Airflow started working without any problem.

Comment: Good to know. To summarize- when the scan of the dag folder takes too long, then the server will get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one of my DAG connects to MySQL database via SSH tunnel, when I connect directly to MySQL it works, but via SSH tunnel it fails. Not sure why, but now I moved to direct connection to MySQL from DAG.

Webserver was not starting gunicorn because DAG was not able to connect to MySQL.

Comment: I think it is the best if you use airflow operators for any kind of connections, unless operator for specific operation not exists

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some of my DAGs have lots of Fargate tasks (I used the ECSOperator), each one of these tasks is using a subroutine I wrote to obtain the subnet ids and security group ids by using boto3's `describe_subnets` and `describe_security_groups`. Apparently these calls have crashed the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have version 1.10.7 and above try to turn on the [DAG Serialization option](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#store-serialized-dags) in both the webserver and scheduler. This will stop the Webservers from parsing DAG files. The scheduler's parser is a subprocess with a timeout per file. You should still find the python file that is probably using a network resource outside a task execution context, and fix that… but this can help.

Alternatively move the dag folder to another named directory, create an empty directory, make the original dag folder directory a symbolic link to the empty one. Start your webserver(s). Now change the symbolic link to your dag directory again.

Personally I don't know why the DAG Bag has to be populated BEFORE responding to any web requests. Why can building it be a background process?